# Load table issue - BCP from flat file - Sybase IQ

Tags: sybase, quotes, bcp, sap-iq

I am getting the below error while trying to do bcp from a flat delimited file into Sybase IQ table.

> Could not execute statement.
>     Non-space text found after ending quote character for an enclosed field.

I couldn't observe any non space text in the file, but this error is stopping me from doing the bulk copy. **|** is column delimiter with **"** as text qualifier and **\n** is row delimiter.
Below is the sample template for the same, am using.

> `LOAD TABLE TABLE_NAME(a NULL('(null)'),b NULL('(null)'),c NULL('(null)'))
>   USING CLIENT FILE '/home/...../a.txt' //unix
>   QUOTES ON
>   FORMAT bcp
>   STRIP RTRIM
>   DELIMITED BY '|'
>   ROW DELIMITED BY '\n'`

When i perform the same query with ***QUOTES OFF***, the load was successful. But, the same query is getting failed with ***QUOTES ON***. I would like to get quotes stripped off, as well.

> Sample Data
>
> > ```
> > 12345|"abcde"|(null)
> > 12346|"abcdf"|"zxf"
> > 12347|(null)|(null)
> > 12348|"abcdg"|"zyf"
> > ```

Any leads would be helpful!

Comment: Can you show us some lines of data?

Comment: @jboi added sample. Not sure, if there are hidden characters at the end of each line. i couldn't trace them from any of my notepads or vim.

Comment: What are the platforms for the files?  Any mix of *nix & Windows?  Other than that, you could strip the quotes with a script before the BCP.  Most of my bcp work has been with ASE, so I'm not as familiar with the issues that can arise with IQ.

Comment: @MichaelGardner flat files are generated from unix environment, and am trying to load them from unix environment, as well

Answer (score 0):

If IQ bcp is the same as ASE, then I think those '(null)' fields are being interpreted as strings, not fields that are NULL.
You'd need to stream edit out those (null).
You're on unix so use sed or perl -ne.
E.g. pipe the file through " | perl -pne 's/(null)//g'" to the loading command or filename.
QUOTES OFF might seem to work, but I wonder if when you look in your loaded data, you'll see double quotes inside the 2nd field, and '(null)' where you expect a field to be NULL.